# "bad magic number" during fresh OpenBSD installation to a USB stick

Tags: installation, bsd, openbsd

Trying to install **OpenBSD 5.2** onto disk **sd0** (*2GB USB storage connected to the computer)*.

Burned **install52.iso** as image to a CD, loaded it into CD drive, and booted off it.

After selecting **[W]hole disk** and then **[A]uto layout**, the following error appears:

```
newfs: cg 0: bad magic number
newfs: fsinit1 failed
...
WARNING! The following filesystems were not properly mounted:
/mnt/home

Continue anyway?[no] _
```

This is as far as the installation goes and gets interrupted.